# mkpinannotation question on mkmapview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have added an mkpinannotation in an mkmapview.

I would like to move the pin to the place i tap on the mkmapview.

Is there an example anywhere?

Help appriciated.

Comment: I think placing pin on tap on map is bad idea. Generally tap on map is used to deselect annotations. You should use longPressGesutureRecognizer (with press time ~1 second) for condition to place pin on map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the gesture recognizer to the map view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 

        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureHandler:)];

tgr.delegate = self; 

 //also add 
<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> to @interface

[mapView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];

[tgr release];
```

Next, implement `shouldRecognizeSimultaneously:WithGestureRecognizer:` and return `YES` so your tap gesture recognizer can work at the same time as the map's (otherwise taps on pins won't get handled automatically by the map)

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer
        :(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer

{

    return YES;
}
```

Finally, implement the gesture handler:

```
- (void)tapGestureHandler:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tgr
{

    CGPoint touchPoint = [tgr locationInView:mapView];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate 
        = [mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView];

    NSLog(@"tapGestureHandler: touchMapCoordinate = %f,%f", 
        touchMapCoordinate.latitude, touchMapCoordinate.longitude);

}
```

In this way you can get the Latitude and Longitude for location which you touch on the Map and once you get latitude and longitude you can easily drop a pin in to that location.